# Groups items in NN groups while retaining order

Tags: c#, .net-core, lambda

Using this this code I can create NN groups of items from a list of items.

```
var itemGroups = Math.Max(1, listOfIds.Count() / itemsPerGroup);

var groups = listOfIds
                .Select((item, position) => new { position = position, item = item })
                .GroupBy(group => group.position % itemGroups)
                .ToList();
```

But these items will not be in order, item one will go in group 1, and item two in group 2 until the itemGroups repeats and starts over at group 1.

I'm wondering if anyone has an elegant solution to group the items in order, ie group 1 has a range of items in order matching the group size, and group 2 continues where group 1 left off.

Ie: Given this list `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }` and grouping into sets of two, the result should be

```
{ { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 } }
```

Comment: Try `group.position / itemGroups` instead of `group.position % itemGroups`